# Ansible register fails when there is no output from shell

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

So basically i want to check somehow if the /dev/xvdb1 is mounted to /var

If answer is yes:

1. don't create dir
2. don't copy files
3. don't mount /var
   etc

If the answer is no:

1. proceed with everything

   ```
   - name: check if /var is mounted
     shell: df -hT | grep /var
     register: df

   - name: Create /mnt/newvar directory
     file: 
       path: "{{ newvar_dir }}"
       state: directory
     when: not df.stdout_lines

   - name: "Get UUID for partition"
     shell: "lsblk -no UUID /dev/xvdb1"
     register: volume_uuids

   - name: Mount /mnt/newvar to /dev/xvdb1
     mount:
       path: "{{ newvar_dir }}"
       src: "UUID={{ item }}"
       fstype: "{{ volume_filesystem_type }}"
       opts: "defaults,noauto"
       state: mounted
     with_items: 
       - "{{ volume_uuids.stdout_lines }}"
     when: not df.stdout_lines
   ```

Error: 
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "df -hT | grep /var", "delta": "0:00:00.005132", "end": "2019-03-10 03:07:22.485343", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-03-10 03:07:22.480211", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

The issue is: if there is no output from df command, ansible brakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could you `ansible_mounts` fact to see if the mount exists and `set_fact` to define a new variable, instead of using `df` and registering results.

See below for reference:

```
- name: Check if /var mount exists
  set_fact:
    is_var_mounted: true
  when: item.mount == "/var"
  with_items: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"

- name: Do everything you want to do if not mounted
  debug:
     msg: "Doing Things"
  when: is_var_mounted is not defined

- name: Skip steps if mounted
  debug:
     msg: "Skipping"
  when: is_var_mounted is defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Very probably /var is not a mount-point and the command returns 1.

```
> df -hT | grep /var
> echo $?
1
```

This is the reason for

```
Error: fatal: ... "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1,
```

Simple condition would be

```
when: /var in ansible_mounts|json_query('[].mount')
```